# Java Classpath watcher API

Tags: classpath, filesystemwatcher

Does Java have any API which can be implemented to get the list of files updated/added/deleted in classpath?

Something which I can register to with the file pattern to look for and call my implementation as soon as a file with the same pattern updates in the classpath?

Or do I have to use file system watcher?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to reproduce hot redeploy in Java EE app servers.

Comment: hmmmm...that's a good observation...this is for my project where we  have development platform which will be generated in 1000's simple .properties and .xml, all I want to know the list of the files updated and once I got that list I do what is appropriate...